# Is there a problem in adjusting the radiator setting too often?

Tags: heating, radiator

I just brought two small Ethernet-type cards, so I could start a project to control the single radiator in my student accommodation over the internet. (#EngineeringStudent)

Now, the when I came back from my holidays, the valve jammed and it was freezing with 18 degrees (I turned it down manually while I was gone). So....

Are there any **obvious problems of getting a motor (servo) to change the radiator setting say, every 6 or 12 hours**, automatically according to the temprature? With this previous history, do I run the risk jamming the valve again? It's just a standard thermostat control which I intended to attach the motor to.

Thanks,
Manfred :)

Comment: Picture?  The style matters.

Comment: @bryce like this one: http://content5.videojug.com/06/06510123-648f-2fa7-43c0-ff0008ce637b/how-to-fit-thermostatic-radiator-valves.WidePlayer.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are inexpensive mechanical controls.  There's no reason they can't be rotated every few hours.  Doing so, however, is mechanically challenging.  Good luck.  Be sure to decouple your rotor (with a belt or gasket) so it does not place undue mechanical stress on the knob.